# Installing iPython3 Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, software-installation, python

It was very easy to install `ipython` and upgrade it to the newest version (2.0) using pip. However, I want to set up `ipython3`, which uses Python 3, and found it more difficult. I finally installed it using `yum`, but I can't figure out how to upgrade to the recent version. Any advice? I am not completely proficient with Linux by the way. I read about pip3 being used but couldn't figure out how to use that.

Comment: Should this be in superuser?

Comment: Where did you find the package?  Are you sure it is compatible with you OS, distribution, and version? If this is not an officially supported package for your distribution you may be causing some problematic behavior.

Comment: No, this is an official package and it works. But it is not up to date. yum install python3-ipython-notebook

Comment: Well, then you are down to compiling and manually installing it yourself from the sources.  Using this process will give you the newer version, however, it will be much more difficult to maintain your system.

Comment: I prefer for it to be maintainable. Do you know anything about using pip3 or pip for upgrading ipython3?

Comment: If the package in your distribution has not been updated to the latest version, it is probably because the updated version has some problems. Unless you wish to compile from sources and maintain it on your own, do not try to update your ipython package through any other means.

Comment: FWIW, here's the tracking bug to updating to the newer ipython version in Fedora. If anyone wants to help out with this, I'm sure help would be welcome. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1006575